# Python: How to append a value in a dict to a list if the value is found in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Example:

```
list1 =['a','b','c','d']
new_list = []
dict = {'a':24, 'b':53 ,'c':26, 'd':9}
```

How would I take list1 and append the associated values of dict into new_list, so as to produce this:

```
new_list = [24,53,26,9]
```

Comment: Have you even tried to answer your own question?

Answer (score 10):

Don't use 'dict' as a variable name, it will shadow the builtin dict() function.

```
list1 =['a','b','c','d']
d = {'a':24, 'b':53 ,'c':26, 'd':9}
new_list = [d[k] for k in list1]
assert new_list == [24, 53, 26, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all the elements in list1 are keys in dict, this is the simplest solution I can think of :

```
list1 =['a','b','c','d']
new_list = []
dict = {'a':24, 'b':53 ,'c':26, 'd':9}

for it in list1:
    new_list.append(dict[it])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 =['a','b','c','d']
d = {'a':24, 'b':53 ,'c':26, 'd':9}
new_list = map(lambda x: d[x], list1)
```

or if you really need to append instead of replacing:

```
new_list.extend(map(lambda x: d[x], list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
for key in list1:
    new_list.append(dict[key])

print list1
```

Example output:

```
[24, 53, 26, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']
dct = {'a':24, 'b':53 ,'c':26, 'd':9}
new_list = [dct[k] for k in lst]
```